# How to apply .css rules on dynamic html elements generated in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-audio

I've read similar questions and tried several suggestions nothing had worked - hope you can help

Scenario:

- loading my website with initial (static) index.html -- looks great css takes fine
- clicking on "next page" button --> **retrieves successfully** the data from DB and dynamically generates the element's innerHTML section.

Problem: the audio player is the only element which doesn't look the same

Initial state: when loading the site first time
[image]

and how it looks after generating the HTML
[image]

All other tags like header image and text do apply the css rules.
The audio player has rules in the css file and has also the following script at the end of `index.html` and I'm suspecting thats the root of my problem not being "fired/called" again for the new generated elements

```
<script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                    var mediaElements = document.querySelectorAll('video, audio'), total = mediaElements.length;

                    for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
                        new MediaElementPlayer(mediaElements[i], {
                            pluginPath: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mediaelement@4.2.7/build/',
                            shimScriptAccess: 'always',
                            success: function () {
                                var target = document.body.querySelectorAll('.player'), targetTotal = target.length;
                                for (var j = 0; j < targetTotal; j++) {
                                    target[j].style.visibility = 'visible';
                                }
                      }
                    });
                    }
                });
    </script>
```

If that's the reason how can I invoke this event on demand and how can I do it from the javascript file?

Comment: It doesn't work like this - if you do inspect element you would see your CSS rules being applied to the player... but player's own CSS might override your CSS rules... kindly check inspect element

Comment: @AkberIqbal I've checked and also copy paste the generate HTML into the index.html file to be loaded static and it looks good